# is it valid javascript to index with square brackets right after declaring with square brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

Normally I would write

```
arr = ['choiceA', 'choiceB', 'choiceC', 'choiceD', 'choiceE'];
position = 3;
answer = arr[position];
```

Just wondering...
Is it valid javascript to write the following?
Will it work cross browser?

```
answer = ['choiceA', 'choiceB', 'choiceC', 'choiceD', 'choiceE'][position];
```

Comment: This is also OK in most other languages that have arrays as first class values (Python comes to mind)

Comment: @missingno it doesn't work in PHP before 5.5

Comment: @JanDvorak: Come on, PHP doesn't really count when it comes to sensible language features does it?

Comment: @missingno I agree; since when `1?2:3?4:5` is `4`, not `2`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I did try it but have been hesitant to leave it in there in case it is not 'correct' !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. This sintax look weird in a first look, but it is perfectly valid. You are getting a position value from an array that is not being assigned to anything.

Comment: Weird? I use it all the time

Comment: @Bergi: 11 years ago, when I started to program, this kind of sintax was pretty weird for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, according to the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2):

```
MemberExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    FunctionExpression
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName
    new MemberExpression Arguments
```

where [`PrimaryExpression` is defined as](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1):

```
PrimaryExpression :
    this 
    Identifier
    Literal
    ArrayLiteral
    ObjectLiteral
    ( Expression )
```

So the construct `ArrayLiteral[Expression]` is valid.

---

It does not necessarily mean that it works in every browser (especially IE has something syntax quirks) but you should assume that it does.

Comment: I awarded answer to first person who posted but thanks for informative answer and reference. So far I've tested iOS5 iPad, ie9, ie8 emulator, ie7 emulator and it works on those

Answer (score 1):

It's valid. It's pretty much the same as doing

```
 some_func_that_returns_an_array()[7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, array literals can be a syntactically valid left part of a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). It does work cross-browser.

I find this construct a very readable alternative to a lengthy `switch` statement, and use it with object literals as well.